# showing that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2x\sin(\frac{1}{x})-\cos(\frac{1}{x})}{x}$ does not exist

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, trigonometry

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2x\sin(\frac{1}{x})-\cos(\frac{1}{x})}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0}2\sin(\frac{1}{x})-\frac{\cos(\frac{1}{x})}{x}$$ ... I know that $$\lim_{x\to 0}2\sin(\frac{1}{x})$$ and $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos(\frac{1}{x})}{x}$$ do not exist, how can I argue then that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2x\sin(\frac{1}{x})-\cos(\frac{1}{x})}{x}$ does not exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x=\frac1{2n\pi}$, for some $n\in\Bbb N$, then$$\frac{2x\sin\left(\frac1x\right)-\cos\left(\frac1x\right)}x=-2n\pi\to_{n\to\infty}-\infty,$$and if $x=\frac1{(2n-1)\pi}$, for some $n\in\Bbb N$, then$$\frac{2x\sin\left(\frac1x\right)-\cos\left(\frac1x\right)}x=(2n-1)\pi\to_{n\to\infty}\infty.$$Therefore, your limit doesn't exist.